# What's wrong with my overloaded function?

Tags: c++, overloading

I'm practicing the overloaded function in my textbook which is finding the smallest number in 2 or 3 arguments. However, I encountered some error like this: functional cast expression list treated as compound expression.

I have tried some methods by googling but still couldn't find the mistake and fix it. Hope you can give some instructions, thanks!

```
double min(double i, double j)
{
    if(i < j)
        return i;
    else
        return j;
}

double min(double i, double j, double k)
{
    if(i < j && i < k)
        return i;
    else if (j < i && j < k)
        return j;
    else
        return k;
}


int main()
{
    double a,b,c;
    cout << "Input the value of a：";
    cin >> a;
    cout << "Input the value of b：";
    cin >> b;
    cout << "Calling min(a,b) for the smallest number : ";
    double(a,b);

    cout << "Input the value of a：";
    cin >> a;
    cout << "Input the value of b：";
    cin >> b;
    cout << "Input the value of c";
    cin >> c;
    cout << "Calling min(a,b,c) for the smallest number : ";
    double(a,b,c);

    system("pause");
}
```

When I do the compiling, the Dev-c++ compiler give me the error message like this: functional cast expression list treated as compound expression.

Comment: Why did you write `double(a,b);` and `double(a, b, c);` ?

Comment: I am stupid guy, thank you for your comment!

Comment: @MooseLuke9407, Take it easy.  We have all made our mistakes.

Answer (score 4):

You're calling 'double' which is a native type rather than 'min' which is your overloaded function.